# Deploy React app using with large files using GitHub Pages

Tags: reactjs, git, github-pages, yarnpkg, git-lfs

The issue I am running into is because I am using files over 100mb and this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB. I am trying to remedy this by using Git Large File Storage. I go through the process and am able to track the files via Git LFS:

```
$ git lfs track
Listing tracked patterns
   *.mov (.gitattributes)
   *.mov (.gitattributes)
   *.pdf (.gitattributes)

$ git lfs ls-files
cca18d4057 * build/static/media/BOL.6bcd7050.pdf
2af10f49e8 * build/static/media/DAOCCA.61340b94.pdf
6a0532b0cc * build/static/media/ebtms.4f75ae1c.pdf
f7ae820210 * build/static/media/tmsvideo.4967bd7f.mov
9e7d2e2bf5 * src/images/new/IMG_2156.MOV
1be822f20d * src/images/new/IMG_2248.MOV
f8fe209393 * src/images/new/IMG_2993.MOV
f7ae820210 * src/images/tmsvideo.mov
cca18d4057 * src/pdf/BOL.pdf
2af10f49e8 * src/pdf/DAOCCA.pdf
6a0532b0cc * src/pdf/ebtms.pdf
```

but when I yarn run deploy, I still receive the same error as before:

```
$ yarn run deploy
remote: warning: File static/media/DAOCCA.61340b94.pdf is 85.94 MB; this is larger than 
GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB        
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - 
https://git-lfs.github.com.        
remote: error: Trace: d11b54c3460af3d02eb47c2fc15d64e1        
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.        
remote: error: File static/media/tmsvideo.4967bd7f.mov is 110.54 MB; this exceeds GitHub's 
file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

I have had no problem deploying a React app to GitHub Pages; however, I have been unsuccessful when trying to combine this and utilize Git Large File Storage.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages doesn't support Git LFS, so if you need or want to use Git LFS for your repository, you need to host it elsewhere.

In the general case, your problem is that your large files are somewhere in your repository's history and you'd need to rewrite that history to remove the large files.  See [the GitHub documentation on this](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/removing-files-from-a-repositorys-history) for more details.  There are other StackOverflow answers that address it as well.