# Using Git Large File Storage (LFS) for JavaScript files

Tags: git, git-lfs

I wanted to use git lfs to track a 200MB Javascript file (it's an array of objects from a dataset). However, when I use it, the pointer file is a .js file too, that has the following:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:13851ea2841feb7424fe785e2c46c161c42e098bef954f3da257d920d9780500
size 244410675
```

From what I understand, it's supposed to be a text file. My .gitattributes file contains only `"COW_Trade_4_0.js" filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text`.

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, since I followed all of the instructions on the tutorial for adding a file to an existing repo.

Answer (score 0):

As far as *Git* is concerned, the text you quoted *is* what you're storing.  That's what goes into the repository.  If you use Git to view the files stored in the commits that exist in the repository, that's what you'll see.

The way Git-LFS works is that it sits "aside" or "atop" Git and *takes over* certain operations.  In particular, when you go to `git add` a file *to* Git, Git-LFS steps in, takes the *real* file contents, shovels them off onto some separate Git-LFS server, and hands Git the pointer file you showed.  When you go to *extract* a file *from* a Git commit, Git-LFS steps in, take the pointer file that comes out of Git, reaches over to the Git-LFS server, grabs the *real* file according to the pointer-file information, and puts the real file into your working tree.

By using Git-LFS *instead of* Git (though you're using Git-LFS through Git commands once you've installed Git-LFS), Git never sees the large file at all.  But if you stop using Git-LFS—i.e., if you continue using ordinary Git commands, but haven't first carefully set up LFS to intercept the Git-level options—all you will see is the pointer files.

The *name* of the pointer file *is* the *name* of the file once it comes out of Git-LFS (if it ever does), so this is all quite normal.  Presumably what you're doing wrong at this point is not setting things up so that Git-LFS can intercept Git operations.

Comment: Thank you! When I go to the website in Google, it says that there's an unexpected syntax (https..."). Is this also because I set up the Git LFS incorrectly?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "go the website in Google": Git isn't a web site and does not provide web services (although there are a lot of front ends that do provide Git service, e.g., GitHub). Git-LFS adds a secondary large file server but still isn't a web site hosting system.

Comment: The website that I've created is on GitHub Pages. When I go to the website I created, there's a syntax error because the text I quoted isn't recognized, and I was wondering if it was also because the Git-LFS can't intercept Git operations.

Comment: Ah: that's a GitHub Pages question, along the lines of "does github pages use git-lfs" or something. I have no doubt it's also already answered, too: for instance [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%253Astackoverflow.com+github-pages+vs+git-lfs) turns up a lot of stuff. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61294090/1256452) seems particularly relevant (but others might have solutions, rather than "no, github pages doesn't support Git-LFS").

Comment: Thank you so much! I never thought that it would be an issue with GitHub Pages. Thanks again!